# Javascript Toggle class on elements with class

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

When any element with `.mytrigger` is clicked, `.myactive` will be toggled on element with `#mytarget`.

I have the following code:

```js
var navclick = document.getElementsByClassName("mytrigger");
for (var i = 0; i < navclick.length; i++) {
 navclick[i].onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('mytarget').classList.toggle("myactive");
  }
}
```

```css
.myactive {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="mytrigger">Button</a>
<div id="mytarget"><p>Hello</p></div>
<a class="mytrigger">Button</a>
```

I need to have multiple triggers and from that this became confusing so I am unable to figure out the correct code. I can't use jquery for this.

Answer (score 1):

Make as many as elements you want with class ".mytrigger" Just put onclick function as mentioned.

I hope this helps:-
If not then please clarify your problem

**HTML CODE**

```
<a onclick="myFunction()" class="mytrigger">Button</a>
<div id="mytarget"><p>Hello</p></div>
<a onclick="myFunction()" class="mytrigger">Button</a>
```

**Javascript CODE**

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("mytarget");
  element.classList.toggle("myactive");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I just changed *document.getElementsById* to *document.getElementById* (removing the s).

```js
var navclick = document.getElementsByClassName("mytrigger");

for (var i = 0; i < navclick.length; i++) {
  navclick[i].onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("mytarget").classList.toggle('myactive');
  }
}
```

```css
.myactive {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <button class="mytrigger">Button
    </button>

    <div id="mytarget"><p>Hello</p>
    </div>

    <button class="mytrigger">Button
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):
It sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mytrigger').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('mytarget').classList.toggle("myactive");
});
```

Using `document.bind`:

```
document.bind('click', '.mytrigger', function(){  
 document.getElementById('mytarget').classList.toggle("myactive");
});
```

Comment: `getElementsById`?

Comment: @bewww, if it solves your problem, do accept the answer :) [Accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)